# Удалить именно тот DOM-элемент, который недавно был создан

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Создаю DOM-элемент, вставляю его в html. Код начинается так:

```
let elem = document.createElement("p");
elem.classList.add("class__elem");
```

Через некоторое время надо будет удалить его из DOM, причём через setTimeout в этой же функции. Проблема в том, что неизвестно, сколько их там было создано до этого: может 1, 2 или 3 таких элемента, и у всех будут одинаковые параметры. last-child тоже не подойдёт, потому что, возможно, после него будет создан ещё один элемент, и тогда это будет уже не last-child.

Так как удалить именно этот элемент, который только что создавался?

Comment: Почему бы в том же коде не вызвать setTimeout? В функции setTimeout сделаете удаление `elem`

Comment: Держать массив/map ссылок. Потом удалять по необходимости

Comment: Если вы объявите `setTimeout` в той же функции, то `callback` будет ссылаться через замыкание на правильный `elem`.

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал, что так можно